# I want to find vowel occurences in Javascript using Switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I want to write a function with a switch statement to count the number of occurrences of any two vowels in succession in a line of text. For example, in the sentence

For example:

Original string = “Pl**ea**ses r**ea**d this application and give me grat**ui**ty”.

Such occurrences in string **ea, ea, ui.**

Output: 3

```
function findOccurrences() {
    var str = "Pleases read this application and give me gratuity";
    var count = 0;

    switch (str) {
        case 'a':
            count++;
        case 'A':
            count++
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

findOccurrences();
```

Comment: It seems you have missed 'io' in 'applicat**io**n'

Comment: if input str = "aeo" what output you want 1 or 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using switch you'd also need a loop and a flag to mark if you have seen a vowel already.

```js
function findOccurrences() {
  var str = "Pleases read this application and give me gratuity";
  var count = 0;
  let haveSeenVowel = false;

  for (const letter of str.toLowerCase()) {
    switch (letter) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
        {
          if (haveSeenVowel) {
            count++;
            haveSeenVowel = false;
          } else {
            haveSeenVowel = true;
          }
          break;
        }
      default:
        haveSeenVowel = false
    }
  }

  return count
}

console.log(findOccurrences());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to find amount of occurrences.

Original string: Pl**ea**ses r**ea**d this applicat**io**n and give me grat**ui**ty

Occurences: **ea**, **ea**, **io**, **ui**

Result: 4

Regex:

- `[aeiou]` means any of these characters.
- `{2}` exactly 2 of them (change to `{2,}` if you wanna match 2 or more characters in a row)
- `g` don't stop after the first match (change to `gi` if you want to make it case insensitive)

```js
function findOccurrences() {
  var str = "Pleases read this application and give me gratuity";
  var res = str.match(/[aeiou]{2}/g);
  return res ? res.length : 0;
}

var found = findOccurrences();

console.log(found);
```

EDIT: with `switch` statement

```js
function findOccurrences() {
  var str = "Pleases read this application and give me gratuity";
  var chars = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  var count = 0;
  
  // Loop over every character
  for(let i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
    var char = chars[i];
    var next = chars[i + 1];
    
    // Increase count if both characters are any of the following: aeiou
    if(isCorrectCharacter(char) && isCorrectCharacter(next)) {
      count++
    }
  }
  
  return count;
}

// Check if a character is any of the following: aeiou
function isCorrectCharacter(char) {
  switch (char) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

var found = findOccurrences();

console.log(found);
```

Comment: I have to do it with switch statement only

Comment: @WaqasUmer i added an extra example which checks the characters based on a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

```
    function findOccurances(str){
    var words = str.split(" ");
    var count=0;
    for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j<words[i].length; j++){
            var char = words[i].slice(j,j+1).toLowerCase();
            var nextChar = words[i].slice(j+1,j+2).toLowerCase();
            switch(char){
                case "a":
                case "e":
                case "i":
                case "o":
                case "u":
                    switch(nextChar){
                        case "a":
                        case "e":
                        case "i":
                        case "o":
                        case "u":
                            count++;
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
    return count;
}

var str = "Pleases read this application and give me gratuity";
var count = findOccurances(str);
alert(count);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code and how it solves the question being asked?

Comment: It works the same way as

 
if(condition){
   if(condition){
   }
}



First of all


* It takes string and break it and save every word of the sentence into an array.

* for loop is executed to traverse each element of array i-e: word.

* Another for loop is used to traverse every char of the word.

*char variable takes the first character and nextChar variable takes the character next to character in char variable.


*The outer for loop takes the first word of the sentence and inner for loop traverse through whole word

Comment: -in inner for loop the outer switch statement checks whether the first char is vowel or not. if yes then the inner switch will check the nextChar for vowel 
- if both corresponding character are vowels then count will be incremented

Comment: @Skully It shows the number of occurances of any two vowels ((ea,ea,io,ui) in the given sentence) using the switch statements only. 
Count represents the number of occurances