# Count the number of occurrences of any two(2) vowels i.e ae,ai,ou etc in succession in a line of text using Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, switch-statement

My function **deleteVowelsS()** with if statements and I know the limitation of switch statement that it only accepts characters or numbers.Am I right?If so then how can I implement the assignment to make a function Function with switch statement to count the number of occurrences of any two(2) vowels in succession in a line of text.Thank you for your precious time.

```js
var def=prompt("Enter the string to count two vowels in succetion : ");
var answer = deleteVowelsS(def);
alert("The vowels in succetion are " + answer+" times");
function deleteVowelsS(str)
{
    var k=0;
    var spl=str.match(/.{0,2}/g);
    for(var i=0;i<spl.length;i++)
    {
        if(spl[i]=='aa'||spl[i]=='ea'||spl[i]=='ia'||spl[i]=='oa'||
        spl[i]=='ua'||spl[i]=='ae'||spl[i]=='ee'||spl[i]=='ie'||
        spl[i]=='oe'||spl[i]=='ue'||spl[i]=='ai'||spl[i]=='ei'||
        spl[i]=='ii'||spl[i]=='oi'||spl[i]=='ui'||spl[i]=='ao'||
        spl[i]=='eo'||spl[i]=='io'||spl[i]=='oo'||spl[i]=='uo'||
        spl[i]=='au'||spl[i]=='eu'||spl[i]=='iu'||spl[i]=='ou'||
        spl[i]=='uu')
        {
            k++;     
        }
    }
    return k;
    
}
```

this is not a duplicate Ive seen this [I want to find vowel occurences in Javascript using Switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874483/i-want-to-find-vowel-occurences-in-javascript-using-switch-statement.But) this includes only taking about only vowels not consecutive vowels which is limitation for switch statement.Thanks

Comment: You're already using regex. Why not just use `/[aeiou]{2}/g`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the reason why you would want a switch case, but here is one solution:

```js
const def = prompt('Enter the string to count two vowels in succetion : ');
const answer = deleteVowelsS(def);
alert('The vowels in succetion are ' + answer + ' times');

function deleteVowelsS(str) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) { // Start with 1 in stead of 0, so you know the previous character exists
    switch (str[i]) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
        if (str[i] === str[i - 1]) {
          count++;
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

However, I would use a single if statement:

```js
const def = prompt('Enter the string to count two vowels in succetion : ');
const answer = deleteVowelsS(def);
alert('The vowels in succetion are ' + answer + ' times');

function deleteVowelsS(str) {
  let count = 0;
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) { // Start with 1 in stead of 0, so you know the previous character exists
    if (vowels.includes(str[i]) && str[i] === str[i - 1]) {
      // it is a vowel, and same character as the previous character
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Here it doesn't look at the exact same character, but it juist counts the number of words where 2 vowels are after eachother at least once in the word:

```js
const def = prompt('Enter the string to count two vowels in succetion : ');
const answer = getResult(def);
alert('The vowels in succetion are ' + answer + ' times');

function getResult(input) {
  const words = input.split(' ');
  let finalResult = 0;
  words.forEach((word) => {
    if (countVowelPair(word) > 0) {
      finalResult++;
    }
  });

  return finalResult;
}

function countVowelPair(word) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (isVowel(word[i]) && isVowel(word[i - 1])) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function isVowel(char) {
  let result = false;
  switch (char) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      result = true;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: the reason is that I am supposed to do that because its a assignement thanks for the answer

Comment: What do you mean? I’ve tested it with multiple strings and it worked. What is happening that you don’t want?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: consider if you input string "aei ioggh aefgfg oufgfg fgfg" are you sure there are 3 words with occurences so it must return 3 this is the case but your function is every time returning 0n

Comment: have you copied it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874483/i-want-to-find-vowel-occurences-in-javascript-using-switch-statement

Comment: Nope, just written this. But this is the first time you are talking about words with occurrences. The question you asked at first is to count the time 2 vowels follow eachother, which is 5 times in the string you have given, but 0 times for 2 of the same characters

Comment: If you want the result, per word, just split the string on a space and then check per word if the count is bigger than 0. If it is, the final count should be +1

Comment: thank you but this was a little confusion probably my fault thanks

Comment: Updated the last snippet to work, but your test sentence `aei ioggh aefgfg oufgfg fgfg` has 4 occurences. The first four words have at least a pair of vowels